# Coverage Probability Poisson parameter in R

Tags: r, code-coverage, poisson

INCIPIT: I found https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9104/coverage-probabilities-of-the-basic-bootstrap-confidence-interval and it partially helped me, but I need to readapt it to the Poisson case.

I am a beginner with R and I am trying to compute the coverage probability for a fixed Poisson parameter (lambda) and with variable sample size (n=1:100). I would like also to run this simulation, that creates random variables, 999 times. My aim is to obtain the coverage probability as an average of the 999 simulations for n=1, n=2, ..., n=100 and then plot the graph, in order to see if the coverage probability ever reaches the 95% nominal coverage probability.

I think that using this code I am achieving the coverage probability for n(1:100), but not replicating the simulation 999 times.

I am getting stuck with it and I think I need some suggestions to clear my mind.

How can I nest a second for loop including the 1000 simulations of the sampling procedure? I think this should be the right procedure, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I leave the code I am using. I got this error while initializing the first for loop, repeated I guess for 1000 times, even if R displays it only for the first 50.

> "1: In x[i] <- rpois(N, lambda) :  number of items to replace is not a
>   multiple of replacement length"

EDIT: I slightly edited the code and now it doesn't show any error, but I still get the coverage probability only for the sample n, while I would like to get the coverage probability for R*n. How can I compute the MLE not only for the n observations but also for 1000 replications? Should I use a forloop?

EDIT2: I tried to rielaborate again and I think that a step by step procedure would be simplier and more useful in order to solve my problema.

First, I want create 100 observations from a population distributed as a Poisson(3) and I repeat that procedure 999 times.

```
B    <- 999                  # number of replicates
lambda <- 3                  # for generating data: true mean
N    <- 100                  # sample size
DV   <- rpois(N, lambda)     # simulated data: original sample
x <- replicate (B, {rpois (N, lambda)
} 
)                                #Replicating the sample 999 times
```

After that, I want to compute the MLE, that is the mean of the observations. Here, I get an error. I would like to obtain 100 values of lambdahat, one for each n. More precisely, I want to first get (DV1/1), then (DV1+DV2)/2, ..., (DV1+...+DV100)/100, repeating it for every replication. But I am doing something wrong since it creates the mean only for the first value of the sum(i.e the first value itself), while I would like to compute 100 different means.

```
getlambda <- function(DV, n) {
          lambdahat <- (sum(DV[1:n]))/n   # lambda*                    
          c(lambdahat)
getlambda(DV, 1:100)

#lower and upper limit of Wald Interval
low <- function(n){lambdahat[n] - qnorm((1 + conf.level) / 2) * sqrt(lambdahat[n] / n)
}
hig <- function(n){lambdahat[n] + qnorm((1 + conf.level) / 2) * sqrt(lambdahat[n] / n)
}
}    

#coverage 
cover <- function(n)mean(lambda >= low(n) & lambda <= hig(n), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Finally, I tried to compute the confidence intervals and coverage probabilities, but I should replicate them 999 times, and I don't know how to use properly the *replicate* command.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to put a vector of 100 length into 1 element of vector x. Do you need the loop there? Can you just have `x <- rpois(N,lambda)`?

Comment: Yes, I can and that's what I did. But in this way I just have 100 values of x, while I would like to sample again those 100 observations for 1000 more times. I hope I am clear about that. I think I messed up while I tried to add the 1000 forloop, because I think I should add it while I am doing the MLE.  Would it be possible to nest a forloop inside another forloop? I'll edit my original post to make it clearer.

Comment: Ok, I think I partially solved the problem using _replicate_, but I still need to compute the MLE for every n and R up to 1000.

Comment: Seems kind of strange to be placing Normal theory bounds around simulated values from an obviously non-Normal distribution. But perhaps you are looking to demonstrate the errors that induces?

Comment: Also seems rather odd to define two functions 1000 times inside a loop and then only use them outside the loop.

Comment: Yes, I want to show that the Wald Interval (i.e. the confidence interval that I am estimating) doesn't perform well with a Poisson distribution, so that's why I am using normal quantiles. About the second message, I am probably wrong because I am a bit confused about loops. So you suggest to include the calculation of the coverage in the loop, right? I'll try to work it out, thank you for the suggestion!